# Importing pictures from my sony camera to my computer

Tags: import, pictures

My pc packard bell running XP has started freezing when I try and import pics from my sony cybershot digi camera.It works ok on my son's pc and has only just started to do this.Any theories?

Comment: What software (if any) are you using to do the import?

Answer (score 0):

is there any antivirus software in your XP PC? some automatic background scans may cause freezing on the system.